# Installing newer Ubuntu version from USB stick to upgrade older version

Tags: boot, upgrade, usb, transfer

Software Updater won't let me upgrade so that is why I'm using the USB stick.I booted the USB and started following the prompts.1st prompt option said I could run it along side the other version. 2nd option said I could remove the old version which would wipe the disk clean to install the new version. I would lose all my personal info,pictures etc. My Home folders are backed up externally. Was hoping the new Ubuntu version would just upgrade like the Software Updater would have done so personal file would not be affected. A Tutorial I read on Ubuntu said it shouldn't affect personal files and would be a smooth transition. Suggestions ?

Comment: For the upgrade you want you need to choose "something else", select all the required partitions and do NOT format. All the manually installed software needs to be reinstalled but personal files as well as all previous software settings are preserved.

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about Ubuntu Server, or Ubuntu Desktop (they differ in this regard; myself I'd do as ChanganAuto says; it's faster than *release-upgrade*, re-installs the additional *manually-installed* apps you had installed & doesn't touch any user files (unless you format) though backups of course should be done before hand (it's easy to make a mistake & have a format ticked; this install is triggered by the no-format).

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
My brother in-law set me up with Ubuntu as he said this is the way to go. He has passed on and I'm trying do my best with upgrades etc. I love the system. The info above I found using Terminal. It is what I have now and I was trying to upgrade to 18.04.6 LTS as shown on the Software Updater. The Updater doesn't upgrade when I choose upgrade. Not sure if I'm Ubuntu server or Desktop as I'm still trying to absorb what I can by searching for info. on Ubuntu.

Comment: info IDistributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial          4.4.0-217-generic #250-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 22 10:07:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: info IDistributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial          4.4.0-217-generic #250-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 22 10:07:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux      ubuntu-desktop 1.361.6      amd64        The Ubuntu desktop system

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/).  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm .  Because you're well past April 30, 2021 *release-upgrades* are complicated by ESM (you need to be fully-updated to *release-upgrade* which now includes ESM).  In your case I'd *upgrade via re-install*

Comment: I've written about the *upgrade via re-install* 30+ times on this site; but also [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) as I use it almost weekly to upgrade support boxes whilst completing a QA-test at the same time; without impacting my installed packages, music libraries etc. I also regularly use it to switch releases (eg. 20.10 reached EOL somewhat recently so the box upgraded to *jammy* ( 22.04), but it'll return to 20.04 when testing 20.04.4 soon).  I looked and can't find one of the answers here sorry.

Comment: In contrast to what @ChanganAuto said; *manually installed* packages, ie. those you'd installed yourself on your system, will be auto-installed IF (1) internet is available at install time with connection made (*any wifi passwords etc entered*), (2) available in Ubuntu repositories for the new release; 16.04 to 18.04 was so long ago I've forgotten what packages/libraries were removed during those years... *we're currently in the jammy cycle*.

Comment: When some one mentions upgrade via re-install what does that entail. Can I find that type of info on Ubuntu ?

Comment: @NewbeeMark, 1. Make a fresh **backup** of all files, that you cannot afford to lose; 2. Download an iso file of Ubuntu Desktop, and/or a light-weight community flavour: Lubuntu or Xubuntu which might work better on an old computer. Make a USB boot drive and Try live before installing; 3. Select the flavour that you like best and run the installer. At the partitioning window of the installer you can decide to keep the home directory (with your personal files and tweaks). Double-check to get that right - and if you happen to overwrite everything, you can restore your files from the backup.

Comment: Actually it is often best to make a completely fresh installation. It is fast and most likely to work well. You get rid of old cruft, that occupies space at best, or causes problems with some of the new software at worst. - And copy your personal files (documents, pictures etc) from the backup into your fresh system.